# Stripe server side PaymentIntentConfirmParams

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I am trying to request Stripe payments purely within the NodeJS server environment (no front end code).

I have got payments working fine using the Stripe charges API:

```
public pay(payment: IPayment): Promise<IPaymentResult> {
        const promise = new Promise<IPaymentResult>((resolve) => {
            const card: Stripe.TokenCreateParams.Card = {
                address_country: payment.country,
                address_zip: payment.zipCode,
                exp_month: payment.cardExpiryMonth,
                exp_year: payment.cardExpiryYear,
                number: payment.cardNumber,
            }
            this.stripe.tokens.create({ card: card }).then((cardToken: Stripe.Token) => {
                const params: Stripe.ChargeCreateParams = {
                    amount: payment.amount,
                    currency: payment.currency,
                    description: payment.description,
                    receipt_email: payment.email,
                    source: cardToken.id,
                }
                this.stripe.charges.create(params).then((charge: Stripe.Charge) => {
                    charge.id;
                    resolve({ chargeId: charge.id, error: false, errorMessage: "", payment: payment });
                }).catch((e) => {
                    resolve({ chargeId: "", error: true, errorMessage: e.message, payment: payment });
                });
            }).catch((e) => {
                resolve({ chargeId: "", error: true, errorMessage: e.message, payment: payment });
            });
        })

        return promise;
    }
```

When testing this code, I got an email from Stripe saying "Update your Stripe integration to avoid declines" to use the new SCA approach. I have switched from the Charges API  to use the PaymentIntents API and got it working with the code below:

```
public pay(payment: IPayment): Promise<IPaymentResult> {
        const promise = new Promise<IPaymentResult>((resolve) => {
            const card: Stripe.TokenCreateParams.Card = {
                address_country: payment.country,
                address_zip: payment.zipCode,
                exp_month: payment.cardExpiryMonth,
                exp_year: payment.cardExpiryYear,
                number: payment.cardNumber,
            }
            this.stripe.tokens.create({ card: card }).then((cardToken: Stripe.Token) => {
                //const paymentIntentParams: Stripe.PaymentIntentConfirmParams = {
                const paymentIntentParams = {
                    amount: payment.amount,
                    confirm: true,
                    currency: payment.currency,
                    payment_method_data: {
                        type: 'card',
                        card: {
                            token: cardToken.id,
                        }
                    },
                    receipt_email: payment.email
                };
                this.stripe.paymentIntents.create(paymentIntentParams).then((paymentIntent: Stripe.PaymentIntent) => {
                    resolve({ chargeId: paymentIntent.id, error: false, errorMessage: "", payment: payment });

                }).catch((e) => {
                    resolve({ chargeId: "", error: true, errorMessage: e.message, payment: payment });
                });
            }).catch((e) => {
                resolve({ chargeId: "", error: true, errorMessage: e.message, payment: payment });
            });
        })

        return promise;
    }
```

I had to remove the typing of Stripe.PaymentIntentConfirmParams because the Typescript compiler did not like the payment_method_data (though the call works).

Is the Typescript definition of payment_method_data in the PaymentIntents.d.ts file wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended integration pattern, as it requires [more stringent PCI compliance verification](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance). Even if you don't wish to [confirm in the client application](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-submit-payment) using the recommended pattern, you can still collect payment details in the client with Elements and `createPaymentMethod` in Stripe.js ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method)) and provide that to your Payment Intent create request as the [payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method).

If you are PCI compliant to handle card details as you're doing, adding the type exception is a suitable workaround for the request structure.